# How to store the json values once up to life time of app removing from mobile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, nsobject

**MY CODE**

**.h**

```
@interface fileHandler : NSObject

@property NSMutableArray *arrCategoryList;
@property NSMutableDictionary *dicCategoryList;
@property NSMutableDictionary *dicAllSubCategoryList;
@property NSMutableDictionary *dicProductList;

+(fileHandler *)getDataHandler;
-(void)categoryStorage:(NSMutableArray *)arrCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicSubCategory;
```

**.m**

```
static fileHandler *internalInstance=Nil;
static dispatch_once_t internalOnceToken=0;

@implementation fileHandler
-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    [self allocateMemory];
    return self;

}

+(fileHandler *)getDataHandler
{

    dispatch_once(&internalOnceToken,^{
        internalInstance = [[fileHandler alloc] init];
        if(internalInstance) {
            NSLog(@"Internal instance created: %@", internalInstance);
        }
    });
    if(internalOnceToken == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Internal instance exists: %@", internalInstance);
    }
    return internalInstance;

}
-(void)allocateMemory
{       NSLog(@"incoming");
        self.arrCategoryList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.dicCategoryList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.dicAllSubCategoryList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.dicProductList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
-(void)categoryStorage:(NSMutableArray *)arrCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicCategory :(NSMutableDictionary *)dicSubCategory
{
//        arrCategory =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.arrCategoryList=arrCategory;
//       [self.arrCategoryList addObject:arrCategory];
//        NSLog(@"inside data handler file==%@",self.arrCategoryList);
//        dicCategory=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.dicCategoryList=dicCategory;
//        dicSubCategory=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.dicAllSubCategoryList=dicSubCategory;

}
```

Here i have created the static thread and then i am trying to store all the values in to mentioned array and dictionary in other class ,once i have stored the values here then i have to access those data to any where in my app.

Is it Possible?

Is it Right Way? 
Another classFile
**.m**

Like this i am trying to store the values in NSobject Class Array.

```
 for(NSDictionary *DicHoleCategories in ArrCategory)
        {

              NSMutableDictionary *DicAllValues=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

              [DicAllValues setObject:[[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"name"] length]  !=0?[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"name"] :@"" forKey:@"name"];

               StrName=[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"image"];
              [DicAllValues setObject:[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"subcategory"] forKey:@"subcategory"];
              if(StrName!=nil)
              {
                subimages=[NSString stringWithFormat:LocalImage"%@",StrName];
                [DicAllValues setObject:subimages forKey:@"image"];
                [arrImages addObject:[DicAllValues objectForKey:@"image"]];
              }
              [ArrName addObject:DicAllValues];
              [arrSubCategory addObject:[DicAllValues objectForKey:@"subcategory"]];

            [dicSubCategory setObject:[DicAllValues objectForKey:@"subcategory"] forKey:@"subcategory"];
            [dicAllValues setObject:dicAllValues forKey:@"hole"];
        }
        [file categoryStorage:ArrCategory :dicAllValues :dicSubCategory];
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x7f8c33c7b220> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

Comment: Why are you repeatedly trying to add the `ArrCategory` array to itself?

Comment: @Wain i have changed that ...

Comment: So which line is yhrowing that exception? And you talk about a thread in the question, where is that and how are other classes using this one?

Comment: are you using `for loop` to change `file class` objects ? if yes please post the code .

Comment: after changes of adding  repeated ArrCategory now the error has gone.

Comment: but the each and every array showing the null ...What i have mentioned in NSobject.

Comment: @HarvantS. s i have tried to store the particular data in for loop but when i have getting that error ,i have changed that outside for loop.

Comment: @HarvantS. as per your suggestion i have changed my code please verify it.

Comment: `[dicAllValues setObject:dicAllValues forKey:@"hole"]` this might be issue.

Comment: Try using Exception Breakpoint. It will indicate you on which line you are getting Exception.

Comment: i will verify that  brother @HarvantS.

Comment: now the error every thing is gone but when i have trying to use the NSobject arrays in another class its shows null :(

Comment: Your rest of code looks fine. You have to debug whats going wrong. Or post data so we can test.

Comment: ok brother :) @HarvantS.

Comment: @HarvantS. that datas everything get stored in my code properly,when i try to get those values its give me a null values

Comment: you can store that particular array into nsuserdefaults for temporary use.

Comment: @Jayesh please explain about the nsuser default explainly

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourMutableArray forKey:@"Key"]; Mutable array can be stored since it is a subclass o NSarray. To get the value in NSMutableArray, NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"]];